# Coordinate extraction from centroïdes of a database

Tags: qgis

[image]
I would like to extract the x,y coordinates from my database under QGIS.
Indeed, each line of my database presents a section of the road "ROAD 500", I initially extracted the coordinates XX, YY of the centroids of each section, but when I use the functions $x and $y to extract the coordinates of all the points building this section, QGIS returns me a column of NULLs.

I've attached a screenshot of my database.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

Since sections of lines are usually lines, `$x/$y` wouldn't return anything, since those [return the X/Y-value of the current point feature](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=geometry#x). You need to hand them a point feature, e.g. the [centroid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=geometry#centroid) of your current feature.

So, `x(centroid($geometry))` will return the x-value of the centroid of your current line segment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.